# SubCategory Joomla 3.9 showing under main menu/category

Tags: categories, joomla3.0

For Joomla 3.0 I'm facing the following issue:

In one of my pages I am representing Group Members (Our Group). This worked fine for a while, but we have now come to the point where the group has expanded and there are people who are departing from the group.

I therefore wish to change "Our Group" to the following:

- Our Group
  -- Active (Our Group)
  -- Alumni (Old Members)

The display is currently set to multiple columns as can be seen here: 
[Example current Group Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZvYS2.png)

Preferably I want a similar banner saying "Alumni" below this containing Alumni sub-articles:
(hopefully this drawing makes sense)
[Preferred Situation Sketch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yi3Hr.png)

Now in order to organize my items I have created a Sub-Category called Alumni (as can be seen) and when clicking that I correctly get the articles from that subcategory:[as can be seen here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y50hf.png)

How should I configure the blog elements so that I get the Group members first (rows of 4, im still working on equal-sized boxes) followed by the [actual last screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y50hf.png) as a separate header/category?

If needed I can provide an overview of my current settings, but it still is rather unclear how Joomla handles these for me.

Site Information: 
Installed Joomla version - 3.9.0 
OS - Linux l
PHP - 7.2.15
MySQLi - 5.5.50

Edit: [Picture of Menu - Our Group](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zDK8l.png)

Comment: Which component you are using to display the group?

Comment: not sure i understand your question,but its done using a Menu, settings added to original post